# Adjusting sidebar and navigation bar positions in CSS

Tags: html, css

I'm working on a rails project. I'm trying to create a navigation bar on top and a sidebar that needs to follow the users around.

Here is the CSS`

```
#sidebar {
    top:0; bottom:0; left:0;
    width:11%;
    background: #b3d9ff;
    position: fixed;
}

#content {
  border:1px solid #000;
  width:100px;
  height:50px;
  padding: 10px;
  margin:5px 0 5px 0;
  position: relative;
}

#navigation-bar {
  width: 100%;
  height: 20%;
  position: relative;

}

ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 2px;
    padding: 10px;
    overflow: hidden;
    background-color: #333;
}

li {
    padding: 10px;
    float: left;
}

#right {
  float:right;
  padding: 10px;
}
```

`

And here is the HTML,

```
    <body>
  <div id = "navigation-bar">
    <ul>
      <li><%= link_to 'Home', home_index_path, class: "btn btn-success" %></li>
      <li id = "right"><button type="button" name="button" class = "btn btn-default">Contact</button></li>
      <li id = "right"><button type="button" name="button" class = "btn btn-default">About</button></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
<div class = "container">
  <div id = "sidebar" class = "container-fluid"></div>
  <div id = "container" class = "container-fluid"></div>
    <%= yield %>
  </div>
</div>

</body>
```

The problem is that the sidebar is overlapping the navigation bar. I don't want any overlapping at all, not even the other way around. I just need the sidebar to start where the bottom of the navigation bar ends.

I added the navigation bar within the container div, but then navigation bar would not occupy the complete width of the page.

I've been at this for two hours now.

Keep in mind, I'm completely new to all of this. Been writing HTML and CSS only for about two weeks now.

Attaching a picture for reference.

[image]

Comment: Adjust the `top` value of the `sidebar` to 20% ?

Answer (score 1):

The navigation bar is 100% width but it is behind the sidebar. Try giving the navigation a greater z-index to bring it to the front.

CSS

```
#navigation-bar {
  width: 100%;
  height: 20%;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 2;
}
```

Here is a [codepen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/eJbEGx)

Comment: That's fine, but then the navigation bar overlaps the sidebar. I don't want that. I need the sidebar to start directly beneath the navigation bar.

Answer (score 1):

If you want the top bar and sidebar to follow the user (aka stay fixed in the window), set both to `position: fixed` with the appropriate `top`, `left`, `width` and `height` values.

For example:

```css
html, body { margin: 0; padding: 0; }

#top {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0px;
  left: 0px;
  width: 100%;
  height: 50px; /* Using px here is better I think */
  background-color: blue;
  z-index: 2;
}
#side {
  position: fixed;
  top: 50px;  /* Using px here is better I think */
  bottom: 0px;
  left: 0px;
  width: 100px;
  background-color: green;
  z-index: 2;
}
#content {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  padding-top: 50px; /* Use the topbar's height + something more? */
  padding-left: 100px; /* Use the sidebar's width + something more? */
  background-color: grey;
  /* Set box-sizing to border-box, to ensure the content block stays within the window, and not expand due to padding */
  box-sizing: border-box;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

```html
<div id="top">
Top bar
</div>
<div id="side">
Side bar
</div>
<div id="content">
Content
</div>
```